# Are there any Objective-C frameworks for shapefile drawing?

Tags: shapefile, osx

Can someone point me to library for this? Which can read shapefiles and render them?

Comment: As a partial solution, you could use [Shapelib](http://shapelib.maptools.org) to read your shapefiles - but that won't render them too.

Answer (score 1):

I agree @anoved
Refer these two articles on reading the shapefile and using opengl to render.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32035/Rendering-Shapefile-in-OpenGL
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1021362/Rendering-Shapefile-in-OpenGL

Per suggestion from @Simbamangu, including excerpts from the source code.There are two main activities in achieving the task-Parse the shapefile vertices ;send these vertices to drawing context using OpenGL.

**Shapefile Parsing**

The excerpt below shows how to parse shapefiles with point geometry.

```
//Include the necessary header file
#include "shapelib\shapefil.h"

//Function to Open Shapefile and parse the info 
void OpenShapeFile(char* fileName,int r,int g ,int b,float fTransparency)
{

    vector<float>vMinX;
    vector<float>vMinY;
    vector<float>vMaxX;
    vector<float>vMaxY;


    SHPHandle hSHP=SHPOpen(fileName, "rb" );

    //Open corresponding DBF  file
    string fileNameString(fileName);
    string fileNameWithoutExtension = fileNameString.substr(0, fileNameString.rfind("."));
    fileNameWithoutExtension.append(".dbf");
    DBFHandle hDBF=DBFOpen(fileNameWithoutExtension.c_str(), "rb" );


    //Push Boundary Box Coods of Every Shapefile that is added
    vMinX.push_back(hSHP->adBoundsMin[0]);
    vMinY.push_back(hSHP->adBoundsMin[1]);
    vMinX.push_back(hSHP->adBoundsMax[0]);
    vMaxY.push_back(hSHP->adBoundsMax[1]);

    if(hSHP == NULL) return;

    //Point Shapefile
    if(hSHP->nShapeType == SHPT_POINT)
    {
        SHPObject *psShape;
        for(int i=0;i<hSHP->nRecords;i++)
        {
            psShape = SHPReadObject(hSHP, i);

            double fX = psShape->padfX[0];
            double fY = -psShape->padfY[0];

            //Plot these points
            MyPoint2D pt;
            pt.dX=fX;
            pt.dY=-fY;
            pt.r=r;
            pt.g=g;
            pt.b=b;
            pt.fTransparency=fTransparency;
            strcpy(pt.strName,fileName);
            vPoints.push_back(pt);
        }
    }
    //Line

    //Polygon

}
```

**Rendering with OpenGL**

```
//Assign Bounding Box Coordinates of Shapefile to glOrtho()
glOrtho(sBoundingBox.fMinX, sBoundingBox.fMaxX,
   sBoundingBox.fMinY,sBoundingBox.fMaxY,-1,1);

//The drawing can be accomplished using below
void draw()
{
  //Render Point Shapefile glColor3f (0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH) ; 
   glPointSize(5.0); 
   glBegin(GL_POINTS); 
   for(int i=0;i < vPoints.size();i++)  
   {
    glVertex2f(vPoints[i].dX,vPoints[i].dY); 
    glEnd();
   } 

    //Render Line Shapefile
    glColor3f (0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    for( i=0;i < vLines.size();i++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for(int j=0;< vLines[i].vPointList.size();j++)
        {
          glVertex2f(vLines[i].vPointList[j].dX,vLines[i].vPointList[j].dY);
        }
        glEnd();
    }

    //Render Polygon Shapefile
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0, 0.0);
    for( i=0;i < vPolygons.size();i++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        for(int j=0;j <vPolygons[i].vPointList.size();j++)
        {
            glVertex2f(vPolygons[i].vPointList[j].dX,
                    vPolygons[i].vPointList[j].dY);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
    glFlush();  
}
```

**Shapefile and Objective-C**

There is objective-c port at https://github.com/initllc/INTShapeFile

Comment: Please give some examples and context! "[Link-only answers are not good answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)." ... if those links don't work in future, we should have a summary of how to answer the question anyway.